# How to use one for loops in different div layouts in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

[image: example of section]

I wanted to list out blog posts in a section having different div layouts. How to do this by using only one for loop.
Or is there any other way, if so, could you suggest how to do it?

Comment: May I ask why just one for loop?

Comment: I think maybe one loop can work. Is there any way with two or three loops please suggest me I am new to django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop. One method would be to utilise a django template tag.

Using for loops for this particular scenario would involve lots of conditions to build the template.

*Note: Bootstap 'Grid System' was used to build layout in template. Information on this is found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)*

**Template**

```html
<div class="row>
  <div class="col-8">
  {{ posts|get_element_by_index:0 }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-4>
    <div class="row">
    {{ posts|get_element_by_index:1 }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    {{ posts|get_element_by_index:2 }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
  {{ posts|get_element_by_index:3 }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  {{ posts|get_element_by_index:4 }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="row">
    {{ posts|get_element_by_index:5 }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    {{ posts|get_element_by_index:6 }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    {{ posts|get_element_by_index:7 }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Template tag**

```py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_element_by_index(queryset, i):
    try:
        post = queryset[i]
    except:
        post = None
    return post
```

Information on how to set up template tags can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

If you want to return the post back as a useable variable to use please look into template built-in `with` found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Comment: @sanket If the answer has answered your question, could you kindly select as right answer.